# KeystoneJS CMS and HTML files

Tags: html, node.js, keystonejs

I am new in KeystoneJS CMS and I am wondering if there is any way to write contact page or any other pages in html. For example if on Contact page I want to add like my address post code and stuffs and maybe a map with location or new fields for contact. Where shall I write all this stuffs. Are so many files and I don't know where to start.

Thanks

Comment: I've not used KeystoneJS but looking at the Github repository, first place I'd look is under `templates/views` for the corresponding page. Is there a "contact.jade" file in there?

Comment: I could see this but I want HTML not Jade. This two are quite similar but different

Comment: You could use this site here to convert HTML to Jade: http://html2jade.org/

Comment: Jade is the default template engine. This page might help you figure out how to turn it off: http://expressjs.com/api.html#app.engine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While there are a number of ways you can accomplish your goal, I suggest you try using an HTML-like template engine. [Handlebars](http://handlebarsjs.com) is one that is commonly used with KeystoneJS.

Here's a working example in the wild:
https://github.com/mgan59/keystone-handlebars-demo/